# AD is separate zone, DCs register in wrong zone

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I have the exact same problem as already described here:
[Windows DNS, AD subdomain as separate zone, DCs register in wrong zone](https://serverfault.com/q/800101/429016)
Unfortunately, there has not been an answer.

We have a public domain contoso.com (that hosts public services) and a subdomain ad.contoso.com that hosts the Active Directory domain services. They are separate zones on the DNS server. The public domain is hosted internally to be able to redirect users of services on contoso.com to internal IP addresses instead of public ones as would be the case when accessing these services from outside our network.

Now the DC servers from ad.contoso.com keep registering themselves as a subdomain inside of contoso.com although dynamic updates on contoso.com are disabled. This results in two trees for "ad.contoso.com": the separate zone called "ad.contoso.com" and the subdomain inside of "contoso.com".

How can I prevent the DCs from recreating that subdomain and regsitering themselves in it?

Domain level: 2008
Operating systems: Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2

Comment: I wonder if you could solve the problem by making sure the ad.contoso.com is of type "Active Directory Integrated" and the contoso.com is "Primary" on one DNS server and "Secondary" on the others. Alternatively, if you right-click on contoso.com and add a new delegation for `ad` it might also do the trick.

Comment: Good idea! I have converted the zone contoso.com now to a "Primary" zone that is not AD-integrated and set up the zone on the other servers as "Secondary" zones. Now the DCs do not register themselves in the wrong zone anymore.